# Is there an R optimization package that can handle integer constraints and non-linear objective functions?

Tags: r, algorithms, optimization, finance, genetic-algorithms

I am looking for an optimization routine that can optimize a non-linear objective function with integer constraints. [NuOPT](http://spotfire.tibco.com/products/splus-nuopt.aspx) for S-Plus, [CPLEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPLEX), or [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/optimization/) include powerful optimization packages for these kinds of optimizations?

Is there any similar kind of package for R? Or is there an optimization procedure (perhaps genetic algorithms) that can solve this problem?

For what it's worth I'm performing a portfolio mean-variance optimization.

Comment: Interesting question. Did (or do) you see anything relevant under the Optimisation CRAN Task View http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: @user603, in a deleted reply, has pointed out that this is likely a *quadratic* program (because that is what CPLEX does and, I would like to add, portfolio mean-variance optimization is usually formulated as a quadratic program).  Usually one is much better off using optimizers written specifically for quadratic programs rather than with general-purpose nonlinear optimizers.  That can help limit the search for packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [most recent issue](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/2011-1_index.html) of [The R Journal](http://journal.r-project.org) contains [Differential Evolution with DEoptim](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Ardia%7Eet%7Eal.pdf), which illustrates how to use DEoptim for portfolio optimization.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to pay for it, there is an interface between R and NAG [NAGFWrappers](http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/R/NAGFWrappers-manual.pdf)

That includes all sort of optimization algorithms, if you know NAG, all chapter E04 is in there.

Obviously you could interface R with NAG writing some C++ code before the package was available, but now it's easier.